# Simple Component and Waveform Issue

Tags: redhawksdr

I have created a simple component and waveform. All the component is suppose to do is output a line of text, specifically a value of a simple property (in this case a frequency value as double data type). I have the component placed in the waveform diagram. When I try to run the waveform from the domain I get this error:

> Failed to create application: testWaveform_203_101836155 'load' failed for component:
>   'maxFreq' with component id: 'DCE:f5144a97-0978-4178-a718-
>   136c72d6cbla:testWaveform_203_101836155_1' with implementation id: 'DCE:afa7ddfd-bc2f-
>   422b-82e3-6876608dab26'; on device id: 'DCE:5fbc2a7a-3f0e-4d38-adb3-e35ecf19b6b8' in
>   waveform 'testWaveform_203_101836155_1' error occurred near line:1909 infile:
>   ApplicaitonFactory_impl.cpp;
>   IDL:CF/ApplicationFactory/CreateApplicationError:1.0

My Python component is extremely simple, all I did was autogenerate the code and add "print self.maxFreq" in the def process(self) function, where maxFreq is the frequency value of 2.45 GHz. What exactly is going wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Double check to make sure that your user has write permissions to $SDRROOT.

Then try running the Device Manager from a command line with a higher debug level to get more information on the source of the error:

```
$ nodeBooter -d /<nodePath>/DeviceManager.dcd.xml -debug 5
```

A few other questions:

- Does this error cause either the Device Manager or the Domain Manager to terminate execution?
- What devices are included in your current node?

Comment: Fixed. I wasn't the one who installed REDHAWK on the machine I was using so my account didn't have permission. Thank you for your help.